# Solve the following differential equation: $y\frac{dx}{dy}-x=2y^2$, with the initial condition $y(1)=5$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the following differential equation: $y\dfrac{dx}{dy}-x=2y^2$, with the initial condition $y(1)=5$.

The thing that is throwing me off (I think) is the $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ instead of what I am more accustomed to: $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.

My attempt at solving this:

I try to rewrite in terms of $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, so I multiply the differential equation by the differential $dy$ and do some algebra.

$y\ dx -x\ dy=2y^2\ dy\\\implies y-x\ \dfrac{dy}{dx}=2y^2\ \dfrac{dy}{dx}$

I think if I can just get a hint as to what method to try to solve this, I should be ok, so please refrain from complete solutions. Thanks in advance.

[In case I wasn't clear, I am just looking for a hint as to what method to use to solve this differential equation. Also, I am fairly new to differential equations, so the only methods I know as of now are separation, and multiplying by the integrating factor, and exact equations.]

Comment: If you want to change to more familiar notation, just interchange $x$ and $y$ everywhere and work with that instead. In the end, switch 'em back. That is, work with $x\frac{dy}{dx} - y = 2x^2$ and $x(1) = 5$.

Comment: The point is that if you solve it for $x(y)$ it is a linear equation. Which can be solved by a standard method. It is *nonlinear* with respect to $y(x)$. So I would suggest to solve the initial equation.

Comment: So keep it in $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ and because it's linear, I can use the integrating factor method to find it? But the initial condition is in the form $y(1)=5$, so would I need to change that into some sort of form $x(a)=b$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After dividing equation by $y^2$, we get $$\frac{y \frac{dx}{dy}-x}{y^2}=2$$ or $$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=2,$$ from which we get the general solution $$\frac{x}{y}=2 y+C.$$ From the previous equation, it is easy to write $y$ as a function of $x$. By using a condition $y(1)=5$, we get $C=-\frac{49}{5}$. So, the final solution is $$x=2y^2-\frac{49}{5}y.$$

Comment: Is there a way that you noticed that the differential equation (after being divided throughout by $y^2$) was equivalent to $\frac{dy}{dx} \left(\frac{x}{y}\right )$, or is it just practice with these sorts of things?

Comment: Well, after a little bit of practice in solving different types of differential equations, it is easy to notice different, more elegant way to solution. Of course, this can be done in standard way, also.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that, this is a [linear first order differential equation](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/lineareq/lineareq.html) which you can solve as $x(y)$. The final solution

> $$ x = y\,( 2\,y+{ c}).$$

Now, use the initial condition to find $c$.